# Material Icon doesn't render in Angular production build

Tags: css, angular, angular-cli, google-material-icons, ng-build

Material Icons are not rendered properly in production when in `::before`/`::after` content. The `font` property disappears on production build.

I have imported Material Icons https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons

#### app.component.html

```
<div></div>
```

#### app.component.css

```
div::before {
  content: 'arrow_drop_down';
  font: 24px 'Material Icons';
}
```

When running `ng build` or `ng serve` it renders the correct icon arrow icon, but with production build it simple renders the text `arrow_drop_down`

I have tried

1. Importing material-icons and adding it in `angular.json` instead
2. Running the production build with `extractCss: false`

Nothing has worked so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The production build doesn't work with CSS shorthands like  `font: 24px 'Material Icons'`

Updating it to

```
font-size: 24px;
font-family: 'Material Icons';
```

solves the problem